# Shuffle data before doing glm, then repeating x times

Tags: r, glm

I have some data that contains a group variable (0/1), and a score pr individual, for about 2000 individuals. The data set looks something like this:

```
ID group score  
A1 1 3.5  
A2 1 3.2  
A3 0 2.8  
A4 0 2.5
```

I want to test if the group variable can be predicted through the score, and have used the following in R:

```
glm(group~score,family=binomial)
```

Now I would like to test my p-value by shuffling the group variable, then doing the glm again. I would like to do this at least 10,000 times, and possibly more, each time printing the p-value for the score in a file, so that there is one row per permutation. I've looked at sample(), but I struggle to combine this with glm() and how to output the p-value only. In a script/formula I would like to easily change the number of permutations, and also change the glm formula if I choose to add covariates.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: The shuffle part is  `data$group <- sample(data$group,N,replace=FALSE)` where `N` is `nrow(data)`  .  All the same, I strongly recommend you read up on "confidence levels" after which you almost certainly can reduce your 10 000 trials to a much more manageable number.

Comment: Thank you! This is similar to what I tried, only this works! As far as I understand, the number of permutations needs to be in the order of magnitude of the p-value to thoroughly test it, so if the p-value is 10^-5 I need 10^5 permutations. Will read more though.

Comment: Presumably you mean `group ~ score` there. You seem to have a good sample size - any particular reason you want to do a permutation test rather than a likelihood ratio test via `anova`? For the permutation test you could try the `glmperm` package on CRAN.

Comment: Yes, typo in the formula. It doesn't look like glmperm will allow the group to be permutated, I get an error saying "var not covariate in formula". Regarding permutation vs ANOVA, permutation is more common in my field, though possibly without any really good reason other than habit. Will look into it, thank you!

Comment: I don't see why replacing `group` with `sample(group)` should not work. Out of interest what is this field you are working in.

Comment: It does work! I think `replicate(N,glm(sample(group)~score,family=binomial)` gives me what I would like, where N is the number of repeats. However, I need to output the p-value for each repeat somehow. I found the formula `p<-summary(output)$coef[,"Pr(>|z|)"]`, but I'm not sure how to incorporate it. I work in genetics, and have only done very basic stuff in R previously.

Answer (score 3):

You're on the right track.

Example (I added one more value to suppress warnings about "fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1")

```
ex <- read.table(textConnection(
"ID group score  
A1 1 3.5  
A2 1 3.2  
A3 0 2.8  
A4 0 2.5
A5 1 2.4"),header=TRUE)

g0 <- glm(group~score,data=ex,family=binomial)
```

Now you need a function to compute a summary p-value (you can do
this on the fly in `replicate`, but this way is cleaner).

```
pvalfun <- function() {
   g <- update(g0,data=transform(ex,group=sample(group)))
   coef(summary(g))["score","Pr(>|z|)"]
}
res <- replicate(1000,pvalfun())
```

Or

```
library(plyr)
res <- raply(1000,pvalfun(),.progress="text")
```

Or

```
library(glmperm)
ptest2 <- prr.test(group~score,"score",data=ex,family=binomial)
summary(ptest2)
```

Comment: Hi, it's the group I need to permute, not the score. I think I gout the following to work: `out<-replicate(N,summary(glm(sample(data$group)~data$score,family=binomial))$coef,"PR(>|z|)"])` 

Now my only challenge is computing power, off to another computer...

Comment: it shouldn't matter in this case whether you permute the group or the score, as long as they are scrambled relative to each other -- you should get identical results.  Do note the comments above that suggest that in this particular example permutation is very unlikely to give you answers different from the standard GLM approach (likelihood ratio test) -- it will just burn a lot more computer time!  `glmperm::prr.test` is also probably a lot more efficient than brute-force resampling ...

Comment: If I understand it correctly, I won't be able to add covariates in a meaningful way if I scramble the score, as some of the covariates are correcting for variation in the score due to missing data.

Comment: true. (beyond the scope of the example you gave, but true).